# Find an equation for the tangent line to the curve $y=8/\sqrt{4+3x}$ at the point $(4,2)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I think the derivative is $-12/(3x+4)^{3/2}$ yet I'm not getting what I'm looking for.  I also think the equation is $3x+16y=44$. Can you help?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What is the slope/gradient of the curve at the point $(4,2)$?

Comment: Hint: evaluate your derivative at $x=4$.

Answer (score 2):

The derivative is $$y'=\left(3 \cdot \left(-\frac 12\right)\cdot\frac{8}{(4 + 3x)^{3/2}}\right) = \dfrac{-12}{(4 + 3x)^{3/2}}$$

So your derivative is indeed correct.

To find the slope of the line tangent at the point $(4, 2)$ is given by evaluating the derivative $y'$ at $x = 4$. This gives us slope of $m = \dfrac{-12}{(16)^{3/2}} = \dfrac {-12}{4^3} = \dfrac{-3}{16}$.

So the equation of the line tangent at $(4, 2)$ is given by:

$$y - 2 = -\frac{3}{16}(x - 4) \iff  3x + 16y = 44$$

So the equation is indeed correct.

Comment: Needs a TU - so +1

Answer (score 0):

We have $$y=\frac8{\sqrt{4+3x}}$$

$$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=8\frac{d(4+3x)^{-\frac12}}{dx}$$

$$=8\frac{d(4+3x)^{-\frac12}}{d(4+3x)}\cdot\frac{d(4+3x)}{dx}=8\left(-\frac12\right)(4+3x)^{-\frac32}\cdot3$$

Comment: You forgot to multiply by $-\frac 12$!

Comment: @amWhy, thanks for your observation, rectified. The downvote came too early when I was editing